# Creating a correct JSON output that follows JSON:API convention

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to parse some JSON that is stored in my database, transform it and then send it to a 3rd party API (by webhook). I am currently stuck at the JSON output format. I am trying to follow the standards of **[JSON:API](https://jsonapi.org/)**.

This is my input from my database column `fields.content`:

```
[{"0": "Page 1, col 1.", "1": "", "2": ""}, {"0": "", "1": "Page 1, col 2.", "2": ""}, {"0": "", "1": "", "2": "Page 1, col 3"}]
```

As you can see, this is a JSON array that consists of objects. Each object represents a row, and each key represents a column. This can be visualed like:

```
___________________________________________________
| COL 1         | COL 2          | COL 3          |
___________________________________________________
| Page 1, col 1.|                |                |
|---------------|----------------|----------------|
|               |Page 1, col 2.  |                |
|---------------|----------------|----------------|
|               |                | Page 1, col 3. |
---------------------------------------------------
```

In my model `Field.php`, I use Laravel casting like:

```php
protected $casts = [
     'content' => 'array'
];
```

Which automatically converts the json string to an array:

```php
dd($content) //$content is the json string from the database
```

Returns:

```php
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    0 => "Page 1, col 1."
    1 => ""
    2 => ""
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    0 => ""
    1 => "Page 1, col 2."
    2 => ""
  ]
  2 => array:3 [▼
    0 => ""
    1 => ""
    2 => "Page 1, col 3"
  ]
]
```

So consider that I do something with this array, like performing a replace on the word `Page` to `Section`:

```php
$out = [];
foreach ($content as $col => $rows) {
    $out[$col] = str_replace('Page', 'Section', $rows);
}
dd($out);
```

This returns:

```php
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    0 => "Section 1, col 1."
    1 => ""
    2 => ""
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    0 => ""
    1 => "Section 1, col 2."
    2 => ""
  ]
  2 => array:3 [▼
    0 => ""
    1 => ""
    2 => "Section 1, col 3"
  ]
]
```

I now want to update my database `fields.content`, to reflect this change. However when re-saving it to the database like:

```php
$field = Field::find(1);
$field->content = $out;
$field->save();
```

It is now saved as an array of arrays:

```
[["Section 1, col 1.", "", ""], ["", "Section 1, col 2.", ""], ["", "", "Section 1, col 3"]]
```

This means that when I send this through my webhook, it no longer follows the same JSON schema like it started out with.

I have tried to json_encode the array, like:

```
$field->content = [json_encode($out, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)]
```

But this doesn't produce the desired output/valid JSON.

Can anyone help me on how to transform my JSON object with Laravel/PHP, and re-save it to my database and keeping the initial valid JSON:API format?

Comment: You shouldn't transform it. The array will be automatically encoded to json. The cast tells Laravel the Model should expect an array. Just update the object as `$field->content = $out;`

Comment: I am transforming it with `str_replace` and wants to save it again to the database. I have already tied doing `$field->content = $out`, and as said in my question, it saves it as an array of arrays: `[[...]]`.

Comment: Well, that's correct. Your initial data is an array of arrays, unnumbered. That's typical of json. If not you would have 3 separate json results and as such 3 entries in the database.

Answer (score 0):

The result is absolutely correct. This is a valid array representation. It the 0, 1... you have is an array index that according to PHP will not reflect when serialized into string.

**What to do?**

Cast to object directly (JSON is an object not an array).

```
protected $casts = [
     'content' => 'object'
];
```

To transform `$content` into a loop, you can have the following instead of `dd`

```
$content = json_decode(json_encode($content), true);
```

To do your parsing, try this:

```
$out = [];

$i = 0;
foreach($content as $con){
    $result = [];
    foreach ($con as $col => $rows) {
        $result[$col] = str_replace('Page', 'Section', $rows);
    }
    $out = array_merge($out, [$i => $result]);
}
$out = json_encode($out);

// Loose the dd($out) part.
```

***Disclaimer***: I didn't get to try it.

Comment: If I am casting to `object`, then I am not able to transform it in my loop (without converting it to an array), and thus being back at square one..

Comment: I just saw your edit. `$content = json_decode($content, true)` does not work, because json_decode() expects a string.

Comment: @oliverbj so in what form do you have your data available then, if not as a string? It literally says in the code you have shown, `dd($content) //$content is the json string from the database`

Comment: @misorude Yes, but I also specify that I use `$casts` on my model: `'content' => 'array'`

Comment: @oliverbj well then stop doing that maybe, if it doesn’t achieve what you want? If you simply used json_decode on the string value you got from the database, your problem would be non-existent - you would get an array _of_ objects, so that you can loop over this, _and_ use $foo->bar syntax to access the object properties inside the loop. And encoding it as JSON again afterwards, would automatically get you the structure you need (because you didn’t _destroy_ that structure by casting it into something else in the first place.)

Comment: @misorude would you mind showing an example of this? I am not quite sure I am following..

Comment: @oliverbj your decode your JSON, loop over the items in the resulting data structure to do your manipulations, and encode the whole thing back to JSON afterwards - not sure where you see any level of complexity here that would require an example, tbh.

Comment: @misorude When I `json_decode($content, true)`, transform it in the loop and then `json_encode($out)`, the end result is the same - an array of arrays. Not an array with objects.

Comment: @misorude,m if he don't convert back to JSON, he will loose all the indexes... Which is exactly what he is trying to avoid.

Comment: @oliverbj did you test the current edit? Any difficulties? Is it working?? I mean the one with `json_decode(json_encode($content), true)`.

Comment: @oliverbj well then stop setting the second parameter to true.

Comment: @RichardMcFriendOluwamuyiwa _“if he don't convert back to JSON, he will loose all the indexes”_ - not sure what you are talking about, of course the result should be encoded back to JSON afterwards. And nothing will get lost, _if_ the parts of the data structure that are objects get treated as such, and are _not_ forced to become arrays to begin with.

Comment: @misorude If I don't set it to `true`, I am not able to transform it: `str_replace('Page', 'Section', $rows);` returns `Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string`. Can I use `get_object_vars($rows)` in this case?

Comment: Not setting it to true and use `get_object_vars($rows)` still returns an array of arrays.

Comment: @oliverbj _“get_object_vars($rows) still returns an array of arrays”_ - exactly, _returns_ it - it did not manipulate your original data object. So you can use the result of get_object_vars to get the _names_ of the properties, and then use those to access the properties on the original object again.

Comment: Okay, if that last part presents a particular challenge, here’s an example: https://3v4l.org/QIjjh

Comment: @oliverbj what issues precisely are you having with the current solution. Tell me exactly what you are facing with it and let me know how to help.

Answer (score 0):

After you did the transformation:

```
$out = [];
foreach ($content as $col => $rows) {
    $out[$col] = str_replace('Page', 'Section', $rows);
}
```

Now you may use the following code to reformat:

```
 $result"[";
 foreach ($out as $value) {
     $string = json_encode($value);
     $string = str_replace('[', '{', $string);
     $string = str_replace(']', '}', $string);
     $result .= $string .",";
 }
 $result= rtrim($result, ',');
 $result.= "]";

 echo $result;
 // [{"Section 1, col 1.","",""},{"","Section 1, col 2.",""},{"","","Section 1, col 3"}]
```